# Picking an item of NSArray using key value coding

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

If you read [listing 4 in the Animation section Apple's Core Animation guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW8), it seems to use KVC and the key path "filters.pulseFilter.inputIntensity" to pick out an object called "pulseFilter" out of an `NSArray`. "pulseFilter" is actually a `CIFilter` named "pulseFilter" by calling the method `setName`.

Now, I don't see the method setName defined anywhere. I also don't believe you can select a specific item out of an NSArray by using a key. Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not necessarily have to go through standard `valueForKey:` or `valueForKeyPath:` of the `NSArray`.

Objects are free to provide own `valueForKeyPath:` method and handle KVC its own way and this is what probably the class of this `selectionLayer` object does.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an object from NSArray using a property name + property value.
Step 1: get your stored object compliant to KVC  (NSKeyValueCoding protocol) by implementing valueForKey: in your custom class.

Step 2: filter your NSArray using NSPredicate (filteredArrayUsingPredicate on your NSArray)

Do you need more detail ?

Comment: Exact. ValueForKey is a method. The handled keys may be your properties but not necessarily. You are free to handle the keys you want.